# How exactly works this method used to query Firebase from an Angular application?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am working on an Angular project interacting with **Firestore** database by **AngularFirestore** following a course on Udemy and I have the following doubt:

First the course show this way to retrieve an array of **Course** object, in this way:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.collection('courses').snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(snaps => {
        const courses: Course[] = snaps.map(snap => {
          return <Course> {
            id: snap.payload.doc.id,
            ...snap.payload.doc.data() as Course
          } as Course;
        })

        console.log(courses);

      });
  }
```

So basing on my understanding it works in this way:

into the component initizialization it is calling the **snapshotChanges()** method on the **AngularFirestore** object (named **db**) to obtain the snapshots of the **courses** Firebase collection. This method return an **Observable** that I can subscribe to obtain the entire collection when an element of the collection change. So when an element change in Firebase it retrieve an array of snapshots. I use the **map()** operator to iterate on each of these snapthsoet element using its content to create and return a new **Course** object that will be inserted into the final **courses: Course[]** array.

Is it reasoning correct? It my understainding is correct, then elsewhere in the course it implement a similar behavior in this way:

```
 ngOnInit() {

    // Retrieve document sapshot, return all the courses with IDs:
    this.courses$ = this.db.collection('courses').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(snaps => {
        return snaps.map(snap => {
          return <Course> {
            id: snap.payload.doc.id,
            ...snap.payload.doc.data() as Course
          }
        });
      }));
   }
```

and here I am finding some problem to understand how it exactly works.

It always retrieve the snapshots of the **coures** Firebase collection but instead to subscribe the returned **Observable** object, it is using **pipe()**. What exactly does **pipe()** in this case?

Then it seems to me that it is iterating on the retrieved snapshot collection (as done in the previous example) but then instead to use a single snap eleement to build the **Course** object it is using **map** a second time on this **snaps** paramether (that should contains the list of snapshots)

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: `pipe` is a method on the observable which allows the chaining of various rxjs operators. `pipe` denotes that you can chain various operators like (`map` [it is not same as array.map of JS], `mergeMap` or many others) to process the data as per the application need. This is the fundamentals oof rxjs. `subscribe` method on the other hand, it invokes the function responsible for the observable. I will highly recommend to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3Eego8xKdk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fist example you have an Obaervable, `this.db.collection('courses').snapshotChanges()`, and you simply subscribe to it.

Subscription means that you ***activate*** the Observable and that, from the moment you subscribe, the function you pass in as parameter to the `subscribe` method will be called any time the Observable notifies something.

In the second example, you set into the variable `this.courses$`, an Observable which is

```
this.db.collection('courses').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(snaps => {
        return snaps.map(snap => {
          return <Course> {
            id: snap.payload.doc.id,
            ...snap.payload.doc.data() as Course
          }
        });
      }));
```

In this case, the source Observable remains `this.db.collection('courses').snapshotChanges()`. With `pipe` you can specify a chain of transformations to the source Observable. Here, the chain is simple, you just apply one `map` operator. The `map` operator transform any data notified by the source Observable using the function passed in as parameter. The result is that the Observable stored in variable `this.courses$` will emit an array of `Course`s any time a new snapshot is notified by the source Observable.

You have to notice though that, in the second example, nothing happens until somebody subscribes to the Observable stored in the variable `this.courses$`.